# Use encrypted Azure credentials when initializing new SecretClient

Tags: c#, environment-variables, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

I've been following this tutorial [Azure Key Vault client library for .NET (v4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-net) trying to learn about Key Vaults in desktop applications. I set up a Service Principal as instructed and gave it access to my Vault, and I was then successful in retrieving a secret using

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
string secretName = "test";
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
```

but only after saving my **AZURE_CLIENT_ID**, **AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET**, and **AZURE_TENANT_ID** as Environment Variables.

What I would like to know is, could these three keys be encrypted within the Environment Variables and still be decrypted via the **DefaultAzureCredential()** method?

Alternatively, could these keys be stored somewhere else, decrypted locally and THEN be passed into the **DefaultAzureCredential()** method?

I tried playing around with the **DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()** overload, but there was no option for passing in the client secret...

I also tried building the token credential object in code using the Fluent.Authentication NuGet and passing that into the **SecretClient** constructor, but I got the error message

```
cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.AzureCredentials' to 'Azure.Core.TokenCredential'
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Or does Microsoft assume that the Environment Variables are a secure enough location for storing the unencrypted client id + secret?

Comment: We have no way to use using the Fluent.Authentication NuGet to create SecretClient. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet. If you consider safety, you can try to use Visual Studio extension(Azure Service Authentication) : https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential_from_azure_sdk/

Comment: Hi @JimXu thanks for the quick reply, I had low expectations regarding the Flient.Authentication NuGet but I had to try it nonetheless..
Do you have any suggestions regarding the encryption of Environment Variables, or explicitly passing them to DefaultAzureCredential()?

Comment: Regarding how to encrypt Environment Variables, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows

Comment: Hi @JimXu thank you for the followup regarding the Secret Manager tool, though it seems like it is only supported in .NET Core projects?

Also the question remains, how to feed the (now decrypted) client_id, client_secret and tenant_id to the DefaultAzureCredential() method?

Comment: @JimXu ok got it how to feed the credentials, instead of DefaultAzureCredential() I instead had to use `var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret));`

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved by yourself, please post your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer by going through Jim's documentation links:
instead of the **DefaultAzureCredential()** method (which uses the Environment variables) i had to use **ClientSecretCredential()**, whose overload allows for specifying the tenantId, clientId and clientSecret:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret));
```

So now for additional security I can simply store these (encrypted) credentials on each dev machine's User Settings.